# unable changing linetype ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to change `color` and line type in my `ggplot`. I am using this code:

```
 a <- runif(84, 20, 80)
a<-ts(a,start = 2009,frequency = 12)
#a<-ts(result$`dataset1$Summe`,start = 2009,frequency = 12)
a3 <- zoo(a, order.by = as.Date(yearmon(index(a))))
p1 <- autoplot(a3)
p1 + scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%m/%Y"),breaks = date_breaks("2 months"), limits = as.Date(c('2009-01-01','2017-08-01')))+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))+
  labs(x = "Date",y="Test") + theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white', colour = 'black'))+geom_line(linetype="dotted", color="red")
```

but only the color is changed. What should I do to change line type?

Comment: Have you tried using integer to change linetype?

Comment: yes, but no success

Comment: I am able to change linetype using integer or words. Can you make your example reproducible?

Comment: I have changed my code. Please see the update

Comment: Your code (with slight cleanup) works for me... I'm able to modify line type to dashed, solid, dotted...

Comment: but for me it doesnt work. How can I explain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`autoplot()` will pick a sensible default for the object it's passed. If you want to customize its appearance it's probably better to use the standard `ggplot()` function.
To be able to do that the `zoo` object should be passed trough `fortify()`:

```
ggplot(fortify(a3, melt = TRUE)) +
    geom_line(aes(x = Index, y = Value), linetype='dashed', color="red") +
    scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%m/%Y"),
                 breaks = date_breaks("2 months"), 
                 limits = as.Date(c('2009-01-01','2017-08-01')))+ 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90), 
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
          panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white', colour = 'black'))+
    labs(x = "Date",y="Test")
```

[image]

(NB: the dashed line at the top is caused by the `panel.background` theme option)

Comment: You could perhaps consider cleaning up `theme` lines - no need to have things in 3 lines...

Comment: You are right, I usually do, I just straight copied from OP code this time